# How to make setOnClickListener on a dynamic imageview

Tags: android, imageview, android-animation, onclicklistener

Working in Android Studio, I need to add in my app a click listener on my imageview which has a certain animation. This is the code I have in MainActivity:

```
myImage.startAnimation(myAnimation);
myImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //DO SOMETHING
    } 
});
```

myAnimation comes from an XML in anim folder which does a translational animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="40%p"
    android:duration="1000"/>
</set>
```

This works fine, although this click listener is set on the space that has the image on the layout (activity_main.xml) and does not follow the animation inserted in the image. If I click on the space which belongs to the image in the layout, the click listener starts even if the image is not there due to the animation.

Is there a way in which the click listener is attach to the imageview in motion?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the xml Translate animation you are using, does not really animate the View's property, it just moves the pixels on the screen and so it just looks like it has changed position, that is why the OnClickListener is still active on the View's original position, because Android thinks the View never really moved.
Simple solution use [ObjectAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator) or even better [ViewPropertyAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator). Both will animate the View's property and so the OnClicklistener will also change it's position with it.